# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (1, 224, 224) but got array with shape (224, 224, 1)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm using `model.fit_generator` and it gives me an error that the input size does not match with expected size. But I reshaped it using `image_datagen.flow_from_directory` using `target_size=(224, 224)`, I cannot set it to `(1, 224, 224)` or it gives me another error.

I am not sure how to check my input size when using the `train_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(target_size =(224,224))`

```
train_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
'C:/output/train/',
    class_mode="categorical",
    seed=seed,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    target_size=(input_size, input_size),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    shuffle=True)

valid_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'C:/output/valid/',
    class_mode="categorical",
    seed=seed,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    target_size=(input_size, input_size),
    color_mode='grayscale',
    shuffle=True)


# https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py
class MyCheckPoint(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        loss = logs["loss"]
        val_loss = logs["val_loss"]
        fileName = "model.%02d_%0.5f_%0.5f.h5" % (epoch, loss, val_loss)
        self.model.save(fileName)

#weight_saver = MyCheckPoint()

model = models.getVGGModel(num_classes)
#model = models. getStandardModel(input_size)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-5, decay=1e-8), loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy)
#model.load_weights("weights.26-1.48.h5")

weight_saver = ModelCheckpoint('weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5',save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)
hist = model.fit_generator(train_generator, validation_data=valid_generator, validation_steps=80, steps_per_epoch=400, epochs=200, callbacks=[weight_saver])

def getVGGModel(num_classes):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(1, 224, 224)))
    # Reshape((784,), input_shape=(1, 224, 224))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1,1), padding='same',input_shape=(1, 224, 224), data_format="channels_first"))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1,1), padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2),data_format = 'channels_first'))

    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', data_format = 'channels_first'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))

    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))

    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))

    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2), padding='same',data_format = 'channels_first'))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax"))

    return model
```

Comment: We need your model definition in order to help you !

Comment: @ThibaultBacqueyrisses Edited!

Comment: Can you show us where you create your `image_datagen` object? There is a parameter for the [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) class for specifying `data_format` as `'channels_first'`. Are you setting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from the input of your model :

```
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(1, 224, 224)))
```

By default `target_size=(224, 224)` will gives you a tensor of shape (224, 224, 1) with the channel last.
But you are specifying an input with channel first for your model.

Just change your input to :

```
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(224, 224, 1)))
```

And of course with that, you don't need anymore to specifying the data_format for all your layers, Keras use channel_last by default.